# How to call post_save signal after adding object to ManyToMany field on another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have two models, `Post` and `Comment`. Now I have a custom function using `post_save` signal on a `comment` object. However, since I add the object to the many to many field after saving it, I cannot get the attributes of the Parent post object.

So I have:

```
comment.save()
post.comments.add(comment)
```

Now I have a function:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def update_comment_count(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    cache.set("post_comment_count_{}".format(instance.post.id), instance.post.comments.all().count())
```

However, this will not work since the post object hasn't added the comment object yet, is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the [**`m2m_changed`** signal [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Post.comments.through)
def comments_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action in ('post_add', 'post_remove', 'post_clear'):
        cache.set(f'post_comment_count_{instance.pk}', instance.comments.count())
```

That being said, [signals are typically anti-patterns](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/). A lot of ORM calls can circumvent signals, and it makes saving objects less predictable. Therefore it might be better to simply encapsulate the logic in a view, and call that function in views where you edit the comments.

Comment: So basically for my use cache is simply better to do the cache update inline and not use signals?

Comment: @ashes999: I'm not a huge fan of signals for several reasons: (a) for ORM calls, especially the ones in bulk, the signals do not run, or at least not very often; (b) it makes updating/saving an object less predictable, since the signals are "hidden" somewhere. If later one of the signals raises an error for some reason, then the update can be "blocked", etc. But in some cases signals can be useful.